# Scrapy Feeds not saving

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm taking a Scrapy spider which succesfully scrapes a few thousand items (see logs below) and trying to store them into S3. However, regardless of the settings I use, no export is saved. The matter gets even worse when I try to save to a local JSON file, and still nothing works.

```
2024-02-20 00:08:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2338579,
 'downloader/request_count': 4507,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4507,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 22670523,
 'downloader/response_count': 4507,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4507,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 12,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 206.962822,
 'finish_reason': 'No data in response',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 20, 0, 8, 39, 297006, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 1780,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'item_scraped_count': 4156,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8667,
 'log_count/INFO': 14,
 'memusage/max': 100188160,
 'memusage/startup': 91996160,
 'request_depth_max': 349,
 'response_received_count': 4507,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4506,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4506,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4506,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4506,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 20, 0, 5, 12, 334184, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2024-02-20 00:08:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (No data in response)
```

I attempted multiple options to save data but all proved unsuccesful:

Option 1: overriding FEEDS in `custom_settings` in `start_requests` to save to S3:

```
storage_full_path: str = f"s3://mybucket/{execution_datetime.strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S')}/{crawler_storage_name}.json"
self.custom_settings["FEEDS"] = {
            storage_full_path: {
                "format": "json",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "store_empty": False,
                "indent": 4,
            }
        }
```

Option 2: inserting feeds in `settings.py` to insert to a local file:

```
FEEDS = {
    "output.json": {
        "format": "json",
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "indent": 4,
    }
}
```

Option 3: overriding FEEDS in `custom_settings` in `start_requests` to save to a local file including URI:

```
self.custom_settings["FEEDS"] = {
            "file:///tmp/output.json": {
                "format": "json",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "indent": 4,
            }
        }
```

Option 4: overriding FEEDS in `custom_settings` in `start_requests` to save to a local file:

```
self.custom_settings["FEEDS"] = {
            "output.json": {
                "format": "json",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "indent": 4,
            }
        }
```

Comment: options 1, 3, and 4 will never work.  I don't see anything wrong with option 2 though.

Comment: @Alexander why will they not work? We cannot override feed settings? My goal was to get the path to be determined at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Scrapy 2.11 the way to change the spider settings dynamically is [to do that in the spider `from_crawler()` method](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider):

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super().from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        spider.settings.set("FEEDS", {...}, priority="spider")
        return spider
```

In older versions you can use the spider `update_settings()` method for that, if your logic can be expressed there.

All of your code modifying `self.custom_settings` doesn't work because `self.custom_settings` is read much earlier than `start_requests()`.